# Amazon: setup credentials to S3 when using elastic-mapreduce with pig-interactive

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-pig

I've started `ec2` cluster with `elastic-mapreduce`, then logged in via `ssh hadoop@ec2...` and started working with grunt by `pig -x local`.

All is good but to access `s3` storage from here I need to specify credentials in the command, like:

```
grunt> ls s3n:///ABRACADABRA:CADABRAABRA@domain/path/...
```

It is not convenient especially because it prints results with full names including these lengthy credentials.

Can I setup them somewhere to be used automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a EC2 instance fired up, you don't want to be running in local mode.  Simply type `pig` in the shell.  If you have an `s3` bucket tied to your account, then you can `cd` to your bucket and access the files in it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Once there, you could load a file like

```
grunt> data = load 's3://[name_of_bucket]/prod.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Comment: Yes I'm working in exactly this manner, but it is annoying it keeps printing credentials for each file when you type `ls` - in my case these credentials are several dozen of digits and it makes the screen look messy...